# How to update column in one table from other table without common key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions

This is probably very basic but I dont know what to search for.

`Table1:`

```
someid value
1      0
2      0
3      0
```

`Table2:`

```
someid value
9      1
10     2
11     3
```

I want to update `Table1.value` with `Table2.value` values row by row, no common key, no where clause just `table1.value row1 = table2.value` row1 etc. Like a horizontal union.

So Table1 should be:

```
someid value
1      1
2      2
3      3
```

I try:

```
update table1
set value = table2.value
from table2
```

But all values are from first row in table2:

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
update table1 
set value = t2.value
from (
  select id, value, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS n from table1
) t inner join (
  select id, value, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS n from table2
) t2 on t.n = t2.n
where t.id = table1.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=08410b94e245bac6a2ecac4694f0254b).
Results for Table1:

```
> id | value
> -: | ----:
>  1 |     1
>  2 |     2
>  3 |     3
```

If you are sure that the ids in `table1` are consecutive with no gaps and start from 1, then the query can be simplified like this:

```
update table1 
set value = t2.value
from (
  select id, value, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS n from table2
) t2 
where t2.n = table1.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=0477b573bc3eb993bb9767aebd30c14d).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following sql statement with `row_number()` window analytic function as :

```
with t as
( 
 select row_number() over (order by someid) as someid,
        value
   from table2
)
update table1 t1
   set value = t.value
  from t
 where t1.someid = t.someid
returning t.*;

someid  value
1       1
2       2
3       2
```

those returning values are from `table1`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6e7953449f6b6491a3fbcb43702a2ebd)</kbd>